# SBT: compile & package -- "working tree not clean"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, netlogo

I am working on a Scala extension for NetLogo ([repo](https://github.com/brodderickrodriguez/Plume-Model.git)). I am following both the Extension API [example](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions-API) and NetLogos [Sample-Scala-Extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/Sample-Scala-Extension).

I am seeing:

```
[info] Done packaging.
To compare two paths outside a working tree:
usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>
[warn] working tree not clean when packaging; target not created
[success] Total time: 6 s, completed Jan 29, 2019, 6:22:00 PM
```

The .jar that is generated does not contain modifications I made to the extension. I think it has something to do with "[warn] working tree not clean...".

Is this the case?
What is the solution?

File hierarchy:

```
Scala-Plume-Model
  build.sbt
  src 
    PlumeModelExtension.scala
```

**build.sbt**

```
enablePlugins(org.nlogo.build.NetLogoExtension)

name := "plume-scala"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.0"

netLogoExtName      := "plume-scala"
netLogoClassManager := "PlumeModelExtension"
netLogoZipSources   := false

scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src"
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-Xfatal-warnings", "-encoding", "us-ascii")
netLogoVersion := "6.0.4"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer:  add `isSnapshot := true` to your `build.sbt` and then the `package` sbt task should start creating the output jar and zip files regardless of the current status of git.

Longer answer: The NetLogo Extension SBT plugin has some expectations about when packaging will occur.  If `isSnapshot` is `false` or unset, the plugin assumes you're trying to do a "production" release.  But for a production release you probably do not want to compile and package off of a dirty repository.  So it warns you and does not create the artifacts.

The normal workflow would be to keep `isSnapshot := true` while you're in development, then once you have all your commits done and are ready for a release, add a commit to set `isSnapshot := false` (maybe along with a version bump for the extension), package and tag the release, then add a commit setting `isSnapshot := true` right away.

Comment: You can also just add `"-SNAPSHOT"` to your version number instead of setting `isSnapshot`, e.g.: `version := "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"`.